# when a user logout and login old date in provider stay and not get update

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, flutter-state

when a user signout the app and then signup as a new/different user then in the category screen old records are stored on the screen, it is cleared automatically when the app is restarted, however.
is there any solution for that?

here is the main.dart file and how I arrange my providers

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => AuthProvider(),
      child: Consumer<AuthProvider>(builder: (context, authProvider, child) {
        return MultiProvider(
            providers: [
              ChangeNotifierProvider<CategoryProvider>(
                key: GlobalObjectKey(context),
                create: (context) => CategoryProvider(authProvider),
              )
            ],
            child: MaterialApp(
              title: 'title',

              routes: {
                '/': (context) {
                  final authProvider = Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context);
                  if (authProvider.isAuthenticated) {
                    return Home();
                  } else {
                    return Login();
                  }
                },
                '/login': (context) => Login(),
                '/register': (context) => Register(),
                '/categories': (context) => Categories(),
              },
            ));
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

this is how I made logout

```
 Future<void> logout() async {
    await apiService.logout();
    this.token = '';
    this.isAuthenticated = false;
    setToken(this.token);

    notifyListeners();
  }
```

and this is my category provider which is not refreshing when new user login

```
class CategoryProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  late ApiService apiService;
  List<Category> categories = [];
  late AuthProvider authProvider;

  CategoryProvider(this.authProvider) {
    this.apiService = ApiService(authProvider.token);
    init();
  }

  Future init() async {
    categories = await apiService.fetchCategories();
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are calling the `init` function in the CategoryProvider's constructor function. That's mean you are calling the function responsible for update the categories just once, in the moment you create the CategoryProvider instance in your main file.

Comment: I'm very new in flutter, can you give me any resources or ideas about how can I solve this?

Comment: Try call this function in other part of you code. For example: in your initState of your page that render you categories

Answer (score 0):

So basically on categoryProvider construction function keep holding a reference of the old token, I don't know why.
so it was calling old user data through the old token.
I just moved ApiService initialization inside the init function and now it working fine.